# How to refresh/update an output after changing it?

Tags: python, list

So when I select "Settings" to change the outputs in "add", then I select "add" and it doesn't update first_out, second_out, and third_out, it only prints the original items in the list. My settings option works btw, after I changed it, it prints the new ones. I have also tried putting the lists inside the loop and still doesn't work. Pls Help

```
first_out = "First"
second_out = "Second"
third_out = "Third"
colon = ": "
a = first_out + colon
b = second_out + colon
c = third_out + colon

while True:

    option = input("Option: ")

    if option.capitalize() == "Settings":

        #First
        change_first = input("First Title: ")
        first_out = change_first


        #Second
        change_second = input("Second Title: ")
        second_out = change_second

        #Third
        change_third = input("Third Title: ")
        third_out = change_third

    elif option.title() == "Add":
        add_first = input(str(a))
        add_second = input(str(b))
        add_third = input(str(c))

        subject = (add_first.title(), add_second, add_third.capitalize())

    elif option == "Print":
        print(first_out, second_out, third_out)

    else:
        print("Invalid Input!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? You can take advantage of the list

```
first_out = "First"
second_out = "Second"
third_out = "Third"
a=[first_out, second_out,third_out]

while True:

    option = input("Option: ")

    if option.capitalize() == "Settings":

        #First
        change_first = input("First Title: ")
        a[0]=change_first


        #Second
        change_second = input("Second Title: ")
        a[1]=change_second
        #Third
        change_third = input("Third Title: ")
        
        a[2]=change_third
    elif option.title() == "Add":
        add_first = input(str(a))
        add_second = input(str(b))
        add_third = input(str(c))

        a.extend([add_first.title(), add_second, add_third.capitalize()])

    elif option == "Print":
        print(':'.join(a))

    else:
        print("Invalid Input!")
```

Comment: print("Thx so much!)

Comment: @Dece ```x=input("Hope you liked it (input yes ;) ): ")```